# General: Howto change Android core API classes?

Tags: android, api, operating-system, patch

This is just a general question for my information. I know how to create standard Android apps, but I was wondering: How is it possible/how do people enhance Android core functions and dig deeper into the system?

For example:
Let's assume I want to adapt the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) class, which is used by many apps. So, for example, one can adapt the class so that the download-text, which is displayed in the Notification bar under the download progress, is somehow changed.

Excuse me the following stupid questions, but I have no idea of these advanced topics, that's why I'm asking here ;-)

- It is possible to change (for example) the DownloadManager class, so that it has extended functionality which will then be used by 3rd party apps, right?
- Can the patched class then be put in the Play Store for other people to download/extend their DownloadManager functionality?
- Will people need Root to be able to install such a change?
- At most important: How can someone alter an Android API class? I'm really a noob here: I don't know where to get the source-code from, how to replace the standard with the enhanced class, what's needed for that, etc. Is there even a tutorial on advanced topics like this?

Please enlighten me a little bit :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is possible to change (for example) the DownloadManager class, so that
>   it has extended functionality which will then be used by 3rd party
>   apps.

Yes, of course, Android source code is opened under Apache license, you can modify this source code, and public into the world. For some detail about `DownloadManager` class and many other class, in Android OS Structure, those class is programmed on upper layer, often totally in Java.

> Can the patched class then be put in the Play Store for other people
>   to download/extend their DownloadManager functionality?

I don't understand your question so much. In Play Store (and another android app store), people upload their **application** (in funny sentence, upload the source code has been compiled), so how can you upload a source code for user extends their apps ?

You can public your source code to github, or another place that programmers often meet, so they can view your source code, and often give you valuable ideas and comments :)

> Will people need Root to be able to install such a change?

if advanced user, they can install new Android OS for their device. But I think, this answer is further than you really need.

> Where to get the source-code from, how to replace the standard with the
>   enhanced class, what's needed for that, etc. Is there even a tutorial
>   on advanced topics like this?

In Android SDK folder, there is a folder named "Source", you can go there and see many Android source code. You can take that, read, and modify what you want. some part of Android is not here, you should google for this, it easy to find on internet.

But you should remember, when you modified this class or that class, it not belong to Android OS again, you must import this class file to your project as normal class.

So,  if you want to modify base Android APIs : those APIs often write all in Java, and you read them and understand carefully, modified some part if you want, and import this class into your project.

And last word, why you should do that :) Because you can **extends** the class you want, and put some additional features for this class. It's easier and nicer.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I'll try to explain again what I mean:

Comment: `So, if you want to modify base Android APIs... import this class into your project.` <br/> Well, I don't have a project. I want to alter the way it works in (my) Android, on my device, for every app which is calling it. Stupid example: I want all my DownloadManager downloads to have a red progress bar. I would assume, I edit the DownloadManager class somewehere deep in my system, and then whenever a 3rd pary app uses the Manager, the progress will be red.<br/> Either I'm thinking in a very wrong way, or I'm not good at expressing my thoughts ;-)

Comment: Yes. if the 3rd party want to use your class, they must imported your class again and recompile entire project. Moreover, you cannot change system class :)

Comment: And as I say, if you want add addtional features, you should extends this class, it's normal in java world :)

Comment: Ok so if I understand you correctly, there is no way to patch a system class so that it works differently for every app which is using it via API? --> A 3rd party app "WebBrowserXY", which is using the DownloadManager API to do downloads, would have to integrate my changed DownloadManager class then, and there's no way to change something in Android itself to have the changed behaviour?

Comment: Additional question from another angle: How is such an app created? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.firezenk.ssb&hl=en (Custom status bar)?

Comment: @ToniKanoni yes, you cannot change system class. if you change, its class must be your own, and not belong to system again. about this app, it's normal :) it can extends status bar, and create new one like this. and it APPLICATION, not class. you should understand this point :)

Comment: Ok, so that's a really good thing to learn :-O My last question: If I make an app where I extend the StatusBar class and install the app, it will replace my default system's status bar? Or how is this done, the replacement? Is it a fullscreen app and an therefore an overlay of the default status bar?

Comment: @ToniKanoni yes, it can replace default system status bar under allow of user :) and this is an application replace by another application. not this class replace by another class. it's main idea.  and if you learn more, you will see it need privileged to change. (and you must declare it in your android app).

Comment: Ok thanks, did not know that you replace system apps like the statusbar with own apps that "easily".