# How to modify Android core api class

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to modify an Android core api class so that any application uses this class will be affected by the changes I made to it? 
for example (just to make it clear), can I change the text color of a toast message to be red, so that any application installed on my device calls:

```
Toast.makeText(this,"hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

will get the toast message displayed in a red text color?

Is rooting my android device required?
What steps should I do to accomplish this task?

I found this:
[General: Howto change Android core API classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876810/general-howto-change-android-core-api-classes)
they said system classes can not be changed

NEW UPDATE:
Is it possible to modify an Android core api class as a part of an app installation process?

Comment: Why don't you just create a custom toaster?

Comment: I want all applications on my device be affected by the changes I made. I'm working on another class(FusedLocationProviderApi), but I gave toast class as a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to modify an Android core api class so that any application uses this class will be affected by the changes I made to it?

You can download the Android source code, make your changes, struggle to turn that into a custom ROM that will work for your device, then replace the Android on your device with that custom ROM.

> I'm working on another class(FusedLocationProviderApi)

That is not an "Android core api class". Each app has its own copy of that class baked into the APK, courtesy of the Play Services SDK's library modules. That class, in turn, uses IPC to talk to the Play Services Framework APK (or the equivalent).

> Is rooting my android device required?

It is conceivable that something like the Xposed Framework would allow you to make changes that have your desired effect. Xposed requires a rooted device, but otherwise I do not know its capabilities. Xposed is not discussed much on this site.

Otherwise, you cannot modify system classes and affect other apps, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.